# Locating a process ID by CPU usage (Ubuntu) using AWK

Tags: shell-script, awk, command-line, command

I have a command that I run to try and list PID's and their CPU usage. I am using `ps -ef`.

Is there a (better) way to do this using `top`? Also, I had a question about my `awk` statement. My variable `$vGRP` is a regular expression. How do I test if `$2` is in `$vGRP`? If so, this can cut out one of my `grep` calls.

I initially wrote this as a "one-liner" that I can just paste into a terminal session, so please forgive the formatting:

```
clear;
printf "Please enter process name: "; read vPNAME;
for i in $(pgrep "$vPNAME");
  do vGRP="$vGRP$i|";
done;
vGRP="${vGRP::-1}";
printf "Seaching for processes: $vGRP\n  PID\tUSAGE\n-------\t-------\n";
ps -ef | egrep "$vGRP" | egrep "$vPNAME" | awk '{print $2, "\t", $4 }';
vGRP=""; vPNAME="";
```

Ideally, I would like something a little cleaner, but I'm not as familiar with `bash` and I want `awk` to check for field 2 in string `vGRP` if possible.

```
ps -ef | awk -v vGRP="$vGRP" '$vGRP~/$2/ {print $2, "\t", $4 }';
```

However, this does not provide output because I assume that `awk` does not read external variables.

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but would `ps -o pid,pcpu -p $(pgrep "$vPNAME")` do what you want?

Comment: Oh snap, that's the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinventing the wheel apparently.

```
ps -o pid,pcpu -p $(pgrep "$vPNAME")
```